# Action Bar Sherlock, Load new activity OnClick

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick, android-fragments

Afternoon.

Basically im using action bar sherlock as my navigation through fragments, one of my fragments layouts consists of four images with buttons underneath, the problem im having is i want to be able to switch to a different activity or XML layout. on the button click. I've tred many different ways to achieve this with no result

Ive got as far as the button click is registered by the device after the app is loaded up but im stuck on were to go for my switch and case code to load up a new layout.

```
package com.westcheshirecollege;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class Fragment_1 extends SherlockFragment implements OnClickListener{

Button button;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle     savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);

    Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:

        // CODE NEEDED HERER TO LOAD ACTIVITY / LAYOUT

        break;
    }
}
}
```

Any Help would be much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Use This..

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:

setContentView(R.id.YOUR_LAYOUT_NAME)

            break;
        }
```

Comment: this dosent seem to, work ive already tired this along with creating an intent, Both methods crash and burn

Comment: Are you still facing Issues? Don't Forget to Change YOUR_LAYOUT_NAME and button1 .

Comment: I was, to be honest i went down a completely different path, and didn't use fragment. but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewActivityname);
             getActivity().startActivity(intent);
         }
```

use this to work on button